# Calculating the absolute minimum in list with negative numbers

Tags: python

I have a list like this-

```
list=[137,136,135,134,119,118,-14,-89,-208,-291,-491,-513,-596,-699]
```

Now I want to calculate the minimum number in the list irrespective of sign but in the final answer the sign should be retained.

For example here the answer would be -14.

Right now I am first splitting the list into positive and negative and calculating the minimum and maximum respectively and then comparing the absolute and returning the answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the [`min()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#min) function with the `key` argument:

```
>>> lst = [137,136,135,134,119,118,-14,-89,-208,-291,-491,-513,-596,-699]
>>> min(lst, key=abs)
-14
```

If multiple items are 'minimal' (e.g. `-14` and `14`), this will return the first one encountered. If you need to handle tie cases, you could use a tuple as a key, e.g.:

```
>>> lst = [14,137,136,135,134,119,118,-14,-89,-208,-291,-491,-513,-596,-699]
>>> min(lst, key=lambda x: (abs(x), x))
-14
```

Comment: Beat me to it :) +1

Comment: and for tie cases?

Comment: Awesome solution. @ubuntu_noob it will be still minimum so tie cases does not matter

Comment: @mad_ sign matters in my case

Answer (score 2):

To solve for tie cases use:

```
a = [137,136,135,134,119,118, 14, -14,-208,-291,-491,-513,-596,-699]
min(a, key=lambda x: (abs(x), x))
#-14
```

Because in this case pure `abs` would return `14` as it comes before.

Answer (score 1):

```
sorted(lst, key=lambda x: (abs(x), x))[0] # better solution would be to use min()
```

with key argument you can specify how it should be sorted. So in this case it will be sorted on the basis of absolute values.
For example

`lst = [137,136,135,134,119,118, 14, -14,-208,-291,-491,-513,-596,-699]`

Then it will be sorted on the basis of abs(x) where x would be every element in the list and hence would return `14` and then `-14` as absolute values of both would be `14` and there comes the role of second argument in the tuple to resolve the ties. So keeping second argument with sign will treat -14 over 14 as `-14 < 14`

Comment: This works, but has time compexity `O(n log n)` instead of `O(n)` of `min()`. I.e. it will be slower for bigger lists.

Comment: @EugeneYarmash I know it can't beat other answers on complexity grounds but I wanted to point out how key works in general so posted the answer.